# Delete query in pgsql 9.5 fails to produce a result

Tags: postgresql

I am currently running postgres 9.5 and when I try to delete information from my database via command line it merely stalls and stops giving me output.

My query is

```
db=# DELETE FROM UNIT WHERE version = 0
db=# \g
```

I'm just confused as to why this isn't doing anything, I believe the syntax is right.

Comment: How many rows has your table?  `version` field has index?

Comment: when i type this in I the command line moves to the next line but fails to offer any indication that this query is working

Comment: My table has 35 rows version is the second column of the table

Comment: can you try using PgAdmin?

Comment: try before deleting running `SET statement_timeout = 1`;

Comment: and in parallel with this stalled statement `select * from pg_locks where granted is false;`

Comment: I used pgadmin and it worked :\ i dunno thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the command ending semicolon:

```
DELETE FROM UNIT WHERE version = 0;
```